# JS Compute width of children element in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason this trivial task has been giving me a proper headache.

So far I have

```
<div class="nowrap">
  <span>Content</span>
  <span>Content</span>
  <span>Content</span>
</div>

<div class="nowrap">
  <span>Content</span>
  <span>Content</span>
</div>
```

—

```
var width = 0;
$('.nowrap').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
console.log(width) //1946
```

Which gives me the **total** sum of all the children under the .nowrap parent. But what I want is to have 2 separate values of each .nowrap 
childrens. So if I had 3 .nowrap divs I'd get something like

```
[443 totalWidth of .nowrap, 755 totalWidth of .nowrap, 457 totalWidth of .nowrap]
```

What do?

https://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/JOOxeL

Comment: So for each nowrap, you want to sum up the width of it's children spans.

Comment: Yes thats the goal!

Comment: So write that.  You know how to do an each, now just move your width inside that each and perform that logic on the children.  `$(this).children()` will get you the spans to each over.

Comment: @A.Wolff thats close but it seems like the values in the console doesnt reflect the values of each children. For instance the first nowrap has 3 children that are 106px, 92px and 90px which should give me 288px in total.

Comment: @SebastianGraz I didn't understand formely what you meant. Now seems what you are looking for: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqqoRd ?

Comment: Yep that looks right. If you post an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is labeled with jQuery, but just for propriety's sake I'll provide a solution that uses only standard functions:

```js
let totalWidths = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.nowrap'),
  nowrap => Array.from(
    nowrap.children,
    child => child.offsetWidth
  ).reduce((total, width) => total + width)
)

console.log(totalWidths)
```

```html
<div class="nowrap">
  <span>div→ [2035] — </span>
  <span> Funky figures </span>
  <span>6'2" • 180° m² </span>
</div>

<div class="nowrap">
  <span> Sick ligatures </span>
  <span class="dlig">rf rt</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for chipping in. I definitely appreciate the non-JQuery answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks for accepting. Should I edit to include jQuery as well since that's what you asked for?

Comment: No thats fine. Most of my code is currently vanilla JS so its actually better.

Comment: Side note; even though I have limited knowledge of JS I can tell that this code snippet is beautiful. :)